# Center div width depending on content

Tags: html, css, centering

I am trying to achieve something that looks like this:

[image: Goal]

I don't know how many *green* elements will be rendered, because that is determined by the CMS and how many components the author decides to put in there.

The requirement is that there are 5 boxes per row before it wraps.

The problem is: `margin: auto` doesn't work when I set the *red* wrapper to `inline-block`.

```css
div.container {
  background: black;
  padding: 10px;
}

div.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.box {
  display: inline-block;
  background: lime;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
      Content 1
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      Content 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add `.container {text-align: center}`. We can set alignment of `inline` and `inline-block` elements with `text-align` css property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div.container {
  background: black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

div.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.box {
  display: inline-block;
  background: lime;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
      Content 1
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      Content 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

just add text-align center  to div.container

Answer (score 1):

As Muhammad Usman suggested, add `text-align: center` to `.container`. The `text-align`-property always refers to the content of the target element.

```css
div.container {
  background: black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

div.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.box {
  display: inline-block;
  background: lime;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
    Content 1
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    Content 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the container div this property

```
text-align: center;
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d0wz4Lyv/)

Answer (score 1):

Centering with `margin: auto` doesn't work for elements that have `inline-block` as `display` property.

You can, however, just center such elements by setting the `text-alignment` of their parent elements to `center`. Then, (re)set the `text-alignment` of the elements you want to center to whatever `text-alignment` you need there.

---

#### Demo

```css
.container {
    background: black;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center; /* Center */
}

.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: red;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left; /* Reset alignment */
}

.box {
    display: inline-block;
    background: lime;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
      Content 1
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      Content 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lr4eay5e/9/)!